# Grunt task with grunt-contrib-less - how to compile multiple stylesheets while maintaining their original .less file name

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-less

I'm building a website with Bootstrap using less. I use grunt to automate the tasks.

In my gruntfile.js I have this part:

```
less: {
  compileCore: {
    options: {
      strictMath: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      outputSourceFiles: true,
      sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>.css.map',
      sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css.map'
    },
    src: 'less/bootstrap.less',
    dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css'
  },
  compileBrandingStyles: {
    options: {
      strictMath: true,
      sourceMap: false,
      outputSourceFiles: false
    },
    src: 'less/branding/**/*.less',
    dest: 'dist/css/<%= what do I put here? %>.css'
  }
},
```

In "compileBrandingStyles" I would like to fetch all *.less files in a folder and compile them into seperate css files with their original file names. No concatenation.

In the folder: `less/branding` I have x number of .less files:

```
theme-1.less
theme-2.less
theme-3.less
theme-4.less
```

I would like to output them in the `dist/css/` folder like this:

```
theme-1.css
theme-2.css
theme-3.css
theme-4.css
```

So how should I write this part to keep their file names?

```
dest: 'dist/css/<%= what do I put here? %>.css'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconfigure your `compileBrandingStyles` Target to this instead:

```js
// ...
compileBrandingStyles: {
    options: {
        strictMath: true,
        sourceMap: false,
        outputSourceFiles: false
    },
    files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'less/branding/',
        src: ['**/*.less'],
        dest: 'dist/css/',
        ext: '.css'
    }]
}
```

See further info on this in the grunt [docs](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically).

---

**EDIT**

If you don't' want the sub folders included in the destination folder use `flatten`.

```js
// ...
compileBrandingStyles: {
    options: {
        strictMath: true,
        sourceMap: false,
        outputSourceFiles: false
    },
    files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'less/branding/',
        src: ['**/*.less'],
        dest: 'dist/css/',
        ext: '.css',
        flatten: true // <-- Remove all path parts from generated dest paths.
    }]
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot for your help.